# burstiness in time data

Tags: variance, data-transformation, dispersion

So i have time of arrival data like this:

time of arrival = [1,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,3,4,6, 8, 9, 10]

we can see that there is a burst between 1.5s and 1.8s.

i have already tried to create a plot of percentage of count over time. the problem is that if i change my time window that percentage would also change and i don't know beforehand what my time window should be.

for example in this case if my time window was 1. for t = 0->1 count = 1,
for t=1->2 count = 4, t = 3->4, count = 1, t=4-5 count = 1, etc and i can see where the burst is...

but if i change the time window to 5, well i get t=0-5, count = 7, t=5-10, count = 4 now the burst is less obvious.

i also tried index of dispersion for the interarrival time, so that i calculate the index for every 5 values by calculating the variance and dividing it by the mean for that 5 vals and then move onto the next but all i'm getting is dispersion of 0.00 - 0.03.

am i calculating it correctly.

any other suggestions on how to determine burstiness without any preset values beforehand becaue my data can vary?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but have you reviewed this doc *Bursty Human Dynamics*? It's comprehensive.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.02580.pdf

Comment: Here is an available online reference which also discusses Bundling effect and within-bundle noise at https://www.ml.cmu.edu/research/dap-papers/dacheng_dap_final.pdf which may be of value.